# Button type in a form, with a control script in php page not working as expected

Tags: php, forms, button, input

I already posted something similar but I didn't receive good answer mainly for my fault, my way to ask wasn't good.
Now I prepared an example to explain what I'm looking for:

I've got a php file with a form and a control script in it, so I post you the stripped example versions:

```
<html>

<head>
<title> Inserimento</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<script> 

  function controllo(){ 
    with(document.insert) {

    if(citta.value=="" || citta.value=="undefined") {
      alert("Attenzione: tutti i campi con asterisco devono essere compilati!");
      citta.focus(); 
      return false; 
    } 

  }
//alert("Controllo effettuato con successo. Il modulo sara inviato."); 
return true; 
} 
  </script>

 </head>

 <body>
 <!-- <div id="scatola" align="center"> -->
 <?php 
  echo"

<form name =\"insert\" onSubmit=\"return controllo();\" action=\"geocode_prova.php\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"post\">
  <div id=\"inserimento\" align=\"center\">
    <h1> Compila con i dati dell'Annuncio</h1>
    <label for=\"citta\">Citta'* </label><input type=\"text\" name=\"citta\" id=\"citta\"/> 

  <button onclick=\"submit();\">Inserisci!</button>
<!--  <input type=\"Submit\" id=\"Submit\" name=\"Inserisci\"/> -->
  </div>
</form>
";

 ?>
<!-- </div> -->
</body>
</html>
```

So there is a simple function that controls the only input field.

The php file called does a bunch of things, I've stripped it down to only this.

```
<?php

require_once("insert_ok.html");
@ header('Location: insert_ok.html');

?>
```

So it only redirects to another page.

My problem is that if I use "input type=\"Submit\" on the first file it works correctly, and if I enter nothing in the filed it stops me, while if I use button onclick=\"submit();\ even if the input field is empty I get the error from the function but then the script let me proceed to the next page.

can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
<button onclick=\"submit();\">Inserisci!</button>
```

to

```
<button onclick=\"return controllo(document[insert]);\">Inserisci!</button>
```